# How to dismiss an anoying "Queued" notification in android 4.4?

Tags: notifications, nexus-5, text-to-speech

Since this morning there is a new notification in my notification bar. The title is "Queue" and there is a progress bar under it that never stops moving. The only information that I see is this text in two lines under it: "Female for German (Germany)". I guess some Text to Speech software is trying to download something from internet. I can not pause or stop it (regardless of pause icon that appears on the left side of the notification).
Some facts:
I use nightly version of cyanogenmod 11 (20140901) and my phone is Nexus 5.

Could anyone help me to remove this notification?

Comment: If you long press on the notification and go to "App info" what app is doing it?

Comment: It says "Download Manager", I did a force stop but the notification appeared again.

Comment: Try opening Google Search > Settings > Offline speech recognition > Auto update  and turn that off altogether, and get rid of any languages you don't want / need.

Comment: I even removed German and disabled Google Now but no change. The notification comes back even after restart. Maybe it is not from text-to-speech or there is a bug in Cyanogenmod nightly.

Comment: It's very possible, those builds are riddled with bugs.

Comment: At least I learned that I can long press notifications. Moreover with long press there is an option to ignore similar notifications and it removed it.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot the notification tickbox! Glad you solved it though. You could post as an answer and accept? It'll get you rep and help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I long pressed the annoying notification and two options appeared. The second one says "ignore messages like this", it dismissed the above mentioned notification.

Answer (score 2):

go to apps> show system apps>google text to speech engine> force stop it should work; otherwise after force stop> disable it must work; if you want to re-enable it, just touch enable again. this annoying notification works because of the very slow download of the offline voice packages of the tts engine.

Answer (score 2):

Open Settings → App management → All apps → Download manager
Open it and click on <kbd>Clear data</kbd>and notification should disappear.

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail on how to do that, for those who might not know?

Comment: Settings->App management->All apps .... Then select Download manager and there will be a button of Clear data. Click it and notification will be gone

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation with "female italian". I found the solution under the "text-to-speech" settings. Enter in "install voice data" and select the language pauses; here youbfind the language pack queued, with an X to delete it.

It worked with my device.

Comment: It looks like the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

IT'S VERY EASY !  . go to Setting>accessibility > text to speech output > and touch the setting icon * lied along with google text to speech (which is ticked by default). > install voice data > here you get a small list of language pack > now find the language which is on your notification bar . if you can't see the notification name clearly then gradually open all the language packs. don't worry these are very few. >  here you get one or two packs (downloading or failed) now you can manage easily....

Answer (score -1):

Just click the notification app info. It will take you to application manager (download manager).  Untick the box that says 'show notification' and it won't show up again.